# Using Typescript type definition from another file

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a Typescript definition `./src/@types/moduleA/moduleA.d.ts` which contains:

```js
declare module 'moduleA' {
  export interface Transaction {...}
}
```

And I want to use it in another type definition file `./src/@types/moduleB/moduleB.d.ts` like this:

```js
///<reference path="../moduleA/moduleA.d.ts" />

declare module 'moduleB' {
  export class MyClass {
    constructor(private transaction: Transaction) {}
  }
}
```

But I'm getting `Cannot find name 'Transaction'.ts`.
Why? Do I have to import it as well?

Thank you

Comment: Probably you have to do `moduleA.Transaction`

Comment: I have tried it as well, but didn't help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So for anyone searching:

only `import { Transaction } from 'moduleA';` should be used.